# dpkg: error processing cgroup-lite (--configure)

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, cgroup

i upgrade ubuntu 12.04 server today and i found with this error:

```
# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree.......
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcgroup1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.1.4) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cgroup-lite, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing cgroup-lite (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cgroup-lite
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
zsh: exit 100   apt-get install -f
```

I have kvm virtuals i managed then with virhs, i can't start if shutdown a vm :(.

```
virsh # start 104
error: Failed to start domain 104
error: Unable to create cgroup for 104: No such file or directory
```

Comment: workaround: download https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cgroup-lite/1.1.2 and dpkg -i cgroup-lite_1.1.2_all.deb, restart libvirt-bin and enter again to virsh :D

Comment: Same problem here! Seems related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cgroup-lite/+bug/1257857. Latest 1.1.4 package was supposed to fix, but looks like it doesn't... I just posted a comment there.

Comment: Yesterday found this bug but is only related :P to me happen on host :( not in a container... i try to create a bug report but i hate launchpad!

Comment: Workaround for install the last version: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cgroup-lite/+bug/1257857/comments/14
The problem is missed space on the config!